# how to debug java web application running on docker image hosted in AWS?

Tags: java, docker, debugging, intellij-idea, web-applications

I have

1. a java application , with source code on git and checked out on my local
2. a docker image of the java web application exposing rest APIs in AWS ECS

the process i Followed

List item

1. downloaded the docker image from AWS ECS
2. created a remote debug in Intellij on port 8000
3. run docker image using command `docker run` on port 6666

i was expecting

1. Intellij to listed to remote JVM
2. break execution and stop at my breakpoints

but actual behaviour is

1. application goes in to execution and no debugging happens

what am/might I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Please check https://ngeor.wordpress.com/2017/03/26/debugging-docker-with-intellij-idea/